# Is there a way to differentiate in jQuery between an initial click and later clicks?

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate

I want my div to grow from 55px height to 125px height when I click on it, and then go back to 55px when I click on it again. This is a bit over my head, so right now when I click on it grows and shrinks simultaneously.  >.<

Here is my code:

```
       $('div').click(function() {
           $(this).animate({
               height: '125px'
           });
       });
       $('div').click(function() {
           $(this).animate({
               height: '55px'
           }); 
       });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: $(this).height() < 125 ? 125 : 55
    });
});
```

Containing the **JavaScript** (`jQuery`) plus a *better* **CSS** approach:
<kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/zSAPU/6/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! The CSS way is a much better approach!

Comment: **+1** nice solution, with CSS, it's better to add it to your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could call the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function within a single "click" event handler for that specific element.

### ***I did an example with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jstol/egCrs/).***

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="small">
        Toggle me!
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
div.small {
    height: 55px;
}

div.big {
    height: 125px;
}
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
$("div").click( function() {
     $(this).toggleClass("big", 1000);   
});
```

***Note: [To be able to provide a second argument](http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) "duration" to "toggleClass()" (an integer) to animate the transition between classes, you also need to be using the jQuery UI library.***

Answer (score 1):

For something like an aesthetic characteristic (like `height`), you should be using CSS to manipulate it anyway. Turns out that it also makes things a lot easier for you jQuery-side, because you can just work on toggling a class on or off, for example.

```
div {
    height : 55px;
}
div.state-enabled {
    height : 125px;
}

// jQuery
$('div').on('click', function () {
     $(this).toggleClass('state-enabled', 'fast');
});
```

Take note that `.toggleClass()` without the animation capabilities come out of the box with jQuery; `.toggleClass()` with animation comes from adding in the jQuery UI lib. This works out for you that `height` needs to be animated, and automagically wires up the appropriate animation calls on the appropriate attributes for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Your events are being bound 2 times.**

one for each instance of the `$('div').click`

That is the reason for the behavior. Bind the event only once

```
var i = 0;
$('div').click(function() {
    i++;
    $(this).animate({
        height: i%2 ===0 ? '125px' : '55px'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be to use a CSS class to toggle the height and manage the transition:

Some HTML:

```
<div class="toggle-div"></div>
```

Some CSS:

```
.toggle-div {
    height: 55px;
    transition: height 1s;
}
.taller { height: 125px; }
```

And now some javascript for the click:

```
$('.toggle-div').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('taller');
});
```

JSFiddle demonstrating this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/PzxXZ/